# List a collection in backend or in frontend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous

I'm pretty new to NodeJS and I need some advices.
I have a page which displays a list of user, I use Mongoose to retrieve this list from the collection. I know two ways for displaying this list :

1) Make the query in backend before the page is loaded, then send the result to the view :

```
// app.js
var users = Users.find({}, function(err, results){
    res.render('list', { users: results});
});
```

2) Make the query on frontend after the page been loaded, in an asynchronous way. Example, with Angular

```
// users.js
var User = $resource('/getUsers');
User.query(function (results){
    $scope.users = results;
});

// users.html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users"{{ user.name }}></li>
</ul>

// app.js
app.get('getUsers', function(req, res){
    Users.find({}, function(req, results){
        res.json(results);
    })
});
```

I hope everything is clear.
What is the best thing to do, in terms of best practice and/or performance ?

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it is actually both, render on the server and on the client. It really depends.

Comment: True. If the list must be refreshed regularly and I keep doing the first way, it would mean I'll need two output methods, one for sending the static content to the view, second to send json if  client needs to refresh the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user experience perspective, it is nearly always better to render on the server first, and then only when the content updates, render on the client (or, actually, querying the server for updated HTML content -- is also often better than rendering on the client). Full client-side rendering usually results into pages that load longer, use significant CPU resources on the client, especially on mobile, and often have some flickering due to asynchronous requests and many partial updates on the page.

Having that said, there are situations when client-side rendering makes sense, e.g. when some content is too long to load at once and it is better to show the page and a progress indicator, e.g. "we are loading your data...". Nevertheless, for most content-oriented websites and portals, nearly complete server-side rendering is a better way to go.

Comment: Seems clear for me, i'll keep doing as much as possible the "old school" style. I ask this because I see a lot of MEAN stack tutorials doing the second way, loading all data to be displayed, asynchronously. Well, I'd say it depends on the amount of data to display

Comment: Going to go ahead and +1 you Andrew. You bring up a lot of good points more concisely than me. :)

Answer (score 1):

To sort of play devils advocate here, I'm going to have to disagree with @Andrew Skylyarevsky.

I consider content driven sites to be on average, more a front end heavy app than a server side app. If the user is being served a page that has content heavily customized to suit their needs, and performance is your goal, you will see the best user experience from serving the customer the bare minimum of content needed to load the page and interact. All further data should be returned via asyc calls such as you would see in a front end heavy app. If it were a server side rendered heavy app you as a user would be expecting subsequent requests for content to result in a server-side page reload.

I agree with @Andrew that one of the drawbacks of the front end approach is the initial load times where the user has to wait for data to come back and render. However, this can and should be mitigated through various techniques. Server vs Front end implementations take about the same amount of effort and complexity on your part as the developer. But if you are looking for a near-seemless experience for the user (performant) you need a well implemented and thought through front end heavy application. Some things should still be done on the back end, but most techniques take place in the front. Serving the user as little as they need to get going and firing off subsequent requests in the background is one such method. It is not easy to tune this experience.

I should note that I'm coming from a background of having worked on several enterprise level applications that sat in the front end of a browser. I have also migrated many server-side applications to front end applications and have seen the benefits both in terms of performance and user experience. So I am biased. Just some food for thought.

Comment: +1 @Patrick Motard. This is what makes StackOverflow so great. I entirely agree with you, so in the end, it is all about a balancing act. I also did migrate server-side apps to client-side to see huge gains in performance in certain scenarios. However, I also did the opposite -- migrate some client-side stuff to server-side. The problem with client-side is that some projects start with good intentions only to end up with huge framework-related (jQuery, GWT, Angular, KnockoutJS, etc.) code bases to just render text articles, which harms UX tremendously and negates any gains over server-side.

Comment: Definitely agree. It's not an easy solution to tackle! No one size fits all.

Comment: The other problem to consider with client-side is of course the size of JavaScript code base. 1 Mb JavaScript is not a surprise nowadays, but on mobile, it may mean that such a website wouldn't open at all for some users because it often takes minutes to load over 3G. I am currently developing for mobile Web mostly, that's why I am hugely biased towards server-side rendering.